# Setting default value of datetimepicker if equal, set to 0

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to set my `datetimepicker` to 0 if the value is equal to the default date which is 'Now'. This is what I have however it always returns null even when the value is changed.

```
private string _BirthDate;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; // Ensures no future dates are set.
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    //dateTimePicker1.Checked = true;
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat;
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}

public string BirthDate
{
    set
    {
        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date != DateTime.Now)
        {
            _BirthDate = value;
        }
    }
    get { return _BirthDate; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string date = Convert.ToString(BirthDate); 
}
```

I know that the `DateTime` class isn't null able but to get around this I just wanted to check if the value was the default and if so just set it to 0.

Comment: What returns null?  `Birthdate`?

Comment: there are some things not clear about your code sample. first, it does not seem to illustrate the 0/null problem as there is no assignment of 0 or null to a datetime picker. second, why is BirthDate converted to a string when it already is a string, and how is that related to the 0/null problem? If you need a "zero datetime", consider using default(DateTime) or DateTime.MinValue.

Comment: Yes, Birthdate is always Null even if dateTimePicker1.Value.Date has a value

Comment: Where are you trying to set it to 0? Not in the code you posted... I doubt it is possible anyway. Why are you trying to put a DateTime into a string anyway? Why not define _Birthday as a `DateTime` or `DateTime?` ?

Comment: Where do you even set `Birthdate` to anything?  Also, please realize that even if the "date" portion of two `DateTime` objects are the same, if the time differs they will not be equal.  You should only compare the `Date` portions

Comment: I wanted to first evaluate if the value was a match with todays date or 'now' and if not set the value in the property

Comment: Ah, and where are you trying to **set** the property BirthDate? In the posted code, you never assign a value to the property, so it remains `null`, which is `Default(string)`

Comment: ah, I see. you don't. you'd need to have an assignment in the form of `BirthDate = ...` somewhere to call the `set` part of the property. As it is currently written, you assume that the setter is somehow implicitely fetching the value from the control on its own. that just isn't happening.

Comment: @maccettura indeed, `if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date != DateTime.Now)` is probably _always_ true. But it hardly matters because the code is never called :)

Comment: Pretty much all that I wanted was, if the user didnt select a date and it remained the default value, set it to 0. If that makes sense

Comment: Perhaps you should be comparing it to the `Date` portion of `Now` (or just use `Today`) instead, otherwise you're including the time: `if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date != DateTime.Today)`

Comment: @dave.2 where do you set to 0?  I cant make sense of what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @dave.2 You are not setting the property anywhere. I suggest you fix that first before trying to solve anything else.

Comment: Cheers realised that now that was my whole issue cheers all solved now

Comment: Debugger is your best friend...

Answer (score 1):

All solved now just had to adjust. As what you guys were saying i wasn't setting the value or the properties so it would all ways be null anyway

```
private string _BirthDate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now; // Ensures no future dates are set.
            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            //dateTimePicker1.Checked = true;
            dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat;
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
        public string BirthDate
        {
            set
            {
                if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
                {
                    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";

                }
                else
                {
                    _BirthDate = value;
                }
            }
            get { return _BirthDate; }
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           BirthDate = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a DateTime nullable

```
DateTime? date = null;
```

Comment: @dave.2 `DateTime?` sure is nullable.